# I want to ignore "\" in the dynamic value

Tags: javascript, regex, performance, jmeter

When i am launching the web application it is generating a state token which is dynamic value looks like this"State_token_g0=stateToken = '00aF\x2D5HSbtfsCjJbYUAayevCC5uvH9Qg5aMGSUvKEM';" and it is getting failed and throwing an error as"{"errorCode":"E0000003","errorSummary":"The request body was not well-formed.","errorLink":"E0000003","errorId":"oaewNC2ocVjS6m_EpiszsjV7Q","errorCauses":[]}".
If the dynamic value generated without "" it is getting executed.
it is not possible to delete \ from the library as well.
Tried multiple regex ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$, [^"]+?, \d+?,\w+?, {"stateToken":([^"]+?),^[A-Z0-9a-z\*~!@#$%^&*()_+|,./<>?]+$,[A-Z0-9a-z\], ^[A-Z0-9a-z\]+$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove backslashes by adding a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after your Regular Expression Extractor and using the following code in the "Script" area:

```
vars.put('State_token_g0', vars.get('State_token_g0').replaceAll('\\\\',''))
```

The line will replace the original value of the `State_token_g0` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with the removed slashes.

Demo:

[image]

In the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for full description of all functions and fields and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: Thanks for  the solution, i am able to generate the state token by ignoring slashes, but in the response body i am getting the error as "{"errorCode":"E0000003","errorSummary":"The request body was not well-formed.","errorLink":"E0000003","errorId":"oaej7PZ0shYS_SOmhxM5NGprw","errorCauses":[]}".
But in response state token is getting generated

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(/\\/g, '');
```

will replace backslashes, could you add this to your regex?

```js
let string = "00aF\x2D5HSbtfsCjJbYUAayevCC5uvH9Qg5aMGSUvKEM";
var minusbackslash = string.replace(/\\/g, '');

//show result in result div
document.getElementById("result").innerText = minusbackslash;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```